# Qt/C++ RTE when asking for selected indexes qtableview

Tags: c++, qt, viewmodel

So for about a week i have been looking for solution of my problem. I have prepared my own model (after QAbstractTableModel) and it is displayed at default qTableView. I added to main menu an option, it is editiog an item:

```
void Window::EditPerson()
{
    console->alert( "Choosing person" );
    //console->alert( /*(QString)"Chosen person " +*/ QString::number( mainWidget->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().size() ) );
    if( mainWidget->selectionModel()->selectedRows().size() <1 )
         return;
    //console->alert( /*(QString)"Chosen person " +*/ QString::number( mainWidget->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().size() ) );
    //Person x = family->GetPerson( mainWidget->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().value( 0 ).row() );

    //EditPersonDialog( x );
}
```

Rapidly after calling this function (which is also the slot) in case there is selected any item i get RTE.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should null-check the return value of `selectedRows()`. Although the documentation doesn't say, I think it might be NULL if there is no selection (which I assume you want to check in the condition).

Comment: After your piece of advice (thanks) I have tried this one http://ideone.com/3W4Lw. After I had called it I got "NO SELECTION!", but there is one item selected.

Comment: Is mainwidget the widget that displays your model?

Comment: Then the selection is not existent when you call EditPerson. I don't know your code, so I can't say anything specific, but I'd look for the earliest point when there is a selection (click signal?) and do what I want to do with it there.

Comment: There is the place, where i had posted two main files of my project: http://ideone.com/nvnEP. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think clicking the menu item might steal the focus from the QTableView. Doesn't that remove the selection as well? (It's been a while since I worked with QTableViews, so I'm not sure)

Comment: No, after I have clicked a menu option The row is being still selected.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help :(